# How to use Cyberduck Credentials to Access WebDAV with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, webdav, cyberduck

I've never used **WebDav** before, but I downloaded **Cyberduck** and used it to connect to an internal work drive and download an entire directory to my desktop. However, for reasons I can't yet identify, I run into random errors where some files don't download. I believe this is related to the network, not **Cyberduck**.

The problem I'm having is that **Cyberduck** doesn't keep a record of the errors and doesn't seem to have very robust error and exception processing.

I'd like to run the same process through a python program so I can make a record of errors.

However, the libraries I've tried I can't connect. I'm sure the problem is user error.

I've tried [`easywebdav`](https://pypi.org/project/easywebdav/) and [`webdavclient3`](https://pypi.org/project/webdavclient3/), but I can't seem to replicate a connection.

For `easywebdav` I've tried to mimic the info I input for **Cyberduck** (see image below) like so:

```
import easywebdav

webdav = easywebdav.connect(host='drive.corp.amazon.com', 
                            username='username', 
                            port=443, 
                            protocol='https', 
                            password='password')

print(webdav.ls())
```

But that doesn't work.

And I've tried changing the `host` argument to `https://username@drive.corp.amazon.com/mnt/...` but no luck there either. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image: Cyberduck Entry]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Cyberduck is configured for using NTLM authentication, but requests by default use Basic authentication.

For connecting to WebDAV server with NTLM authentication you can use 3rd party library which implements it, for example [requests-ntlm](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm):

```python
from webdav3.client import Client
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

options = {
 'webdav_hostname': "https://webdav.server.ru"
}

client = Client(options)
# Configure authentication method 
client.session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\username','password')
```

Comment: Thanks Evgeny. Really appreciate the engineer behind webdav3 weighing in. I tried the solution recommended above, but I'm getting an error still. webdav3.exceptions.NoConnection: No connection with https://drive.corp.amazon.com

This may be a dumb question, but what should I be typing in the "domain\\username"? Do I replace the "domain" string with the actual domain? Say drive.corp.amazon.com in this instance?

Comment: I think for the average person experiencing a similar problem, this would work. I've used your requests_ntlm in other solutions at my workplace, and its worked well where basic authentication fails.

Their doesn't appear to be an obvious, python level solution to the problem I'm facing. Something about the internal work application I'm using just simply has a lot of problems.